# How are different parts of an extremely fast spinning disk affected by time dilation?

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation, rotation

Especially the outer edges will have an extremely high relative velocity from the perspective of an external observer. In the [Twin Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_paradox), two objects age differently due to different reference frames. Do different parts of the disk age differently due to rotation? What about the center of the disk?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_paradox